# What is the advantage of N-Triples over CSV for storing RDF triples?

Tags: csv, rdf, n-triples

N-Triples is a line based serialization format for an RDF graph. Each line represents the subject, predicate and object of an RDF Triple separated by whitespace and ended with a dot like:

```
<http://one.example/subject1> <http://one.example/predicate1> <http://one.example/object1> .
```

More details can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/n-triples/

But why is it necessary to define such a format, if one could serialize RDF Triples simply using CSV like

```
http://one.example/subject1, http://one.example/predicate1, http://one.example/object1
```

I could even easily extend to support N-Quads, N-Quints, ... using CSV. What are the advantages of N-Triples over CSV for serializing RDF triples?

Comment: This is probably off-topic, since it seems like it would be primarily opinion based.  Nonetheless, the main advantages are probably that it makes the representation of triples much more like the one used in other RDF tools; e.g., that N-Triples content can be injected into SPARQL queries, and N3 and Turtle documents.  Since there's variation in how people encode strings and the like in CSV, defining a new standard means that there's a definite specification to work from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the original editor of N-Triples and implemented it in Raptor http://librdf.org/raptor/ both the N-Triples original and the 2013 version.

There are multiple answers to this but it's basically ambiguity.  CSV can't distinguish between a URI that looks like `http://foo.com/` and a string `http://foo.com/`

In CSV

```
http://foo.com/,http://foo.com/,http://foo.com/
```

this could be a triple

```
(URI http://foo.com/, URI http://foo.com/, URI http://foo.com/)
```

or

```
(URI http://foo.com/, URI http://foo.com/, Literal http://foo.com/)
```

N-Triples adds `<>` and `""` for distinguishing these cases

Comment: But why is it important to distinguish between an URI and a Literal that looks like an URI? If I can parse a string as URI because it looks like xxx://yyy I could treat it as URI. If not, I treat it as Literal. Is it really necessary to introduce additional markup like `<>` for that?

Comment: @asmaier if an author A writes an RDF model to N-Triples and consumer B then reads that file, you want it to be identical to the original model - the whole point is for B to understand A's intent. That can only be guaranteed if the file syntax format does not introduce ambiguity.

Comment: Ok, I see the point now. Answer accepted.